# How to setup apache superset local flask backed correctly?

Tags: python, apache-superset

I always get the following error while setting up the local backend for apache-superset following this article https://superset.apache.org/docs/Contributing/local-backend/

##### How to reproduce the bug

clone this repo https://github.com/apache/superset

1. `cd superset`

```sh
# Create a virtual environment and activate it (recommended)
python3 -m venv venv # setup a python3 virtualenv
source venv/bin/activate

# Install external dependencies
pip install -r requirements/testing.txt

# Install Superset in editable (development) mode
pip install -e .

# Initialize the database
superset db upgrade

# Create an admin user in your metadata database (use `admin` as username to be able to load the examples)
superset fab create-admin

# Create default roles and permissions
superset init
```

#### Expected results

Apache superset must start successfully but upon running superset init the following error occurs frequently

#### Actual results

superset init command exits with exit code 1 and throwing following output.
clearly it can be seen the error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dbs.allow_file_upload`

```sh
(venv) (base) mohnish@MMMDVMOHNISHSINT superset % superset init
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    WARNING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.
Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool to help you generate 
a sufficiently random sequence, ex: openssl rand -base64 42
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
logging was configured successfully
2022-02-09 12:27:38,482:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2022-02-09 12:27:38,492:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:201: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn(
Syncing role definition
2022-02-09 12:27:40,476:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing role definition
Syncing Admin perms
2022-02-09 12:27:40,483:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Admin perms
Syncing Alpha perms
2022-02-09 12:27:40,548:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Alpha perms
Syncing Gamma perms
2022-02-09 12:27:40,613:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Gamma perms
Syncing granter perms
2022-02-09 12:27:40,679:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing granter perms
Syncing sql_lab perms
2022-02-09 12:27:40,742:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing sql_lab perms
Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
2022-02-09 12:27:40,805:INFO:superset.security.manager:Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
Creating missing datasource permissions.
2022-02-09 12:27:40,864:INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing datasource permissions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dbs.allow_file_upload

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/superset/cli/main.py", line 61, in init
    security_manager.sync_role_definitions()
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/superset/security/manager.py", line 726, in sync_role_definitions
    self.create_missing_perms()
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/superset/security/manager.py", line 668, in create_missing_perms
    merge_pv("datasource_access", datasource.get_perm())
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 634, in get_perm
    return f"[{self.database}].[{self.table_name}](id:{self.id})"
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 294, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 730, in get
    value = self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 759, in _load_for_state
    return self._emit_lazyload(
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 847, in _emit_lazyload
    q(session)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 615, in _load_on_pk_identity
    result = list(bq.for_session(self.session).params(**params))
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 444, in __iter__
    return q._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/mohnish/Desktop/superset/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: dbs.allow_file_upload
[SQL: SELECT dbs.uuid AS dbs_uuid, dbs.created_on AS dbs_created_on, dbs.changed_on AS dbs_changed_on, dbs.id AS dbs_id, dbs.verbose_name AS dbs_verbose_name, dbs.database_name AS dbs_database_name, dbs.sqlalchemy_uri AS dbs_sqlalchemy_uri, dbs.password AS dbs_password, dbs.cache_timeout AS dbs_cache_timeout, dbs.select_as_create_table_as AS dbs_select_as_create_table_as, dbs.expose_in_sqllab AS dbs_expose_in_sqllab, dbs.configuration_method AS dbs_configuration_method, dbs.allow_run_async AS dbs_allow_run_async, dbs.allow_file_upload AS dbs_allow_file_upload, dbs.allow_ctas AS dbs_allow_ctas, dbs.allow_cvas AS dbs_allow_cvas, dbs.allow_dml AS dbs_allow_dml, dbs.force_ctas_schema AS dbs_force_ctas_schema, dbs.allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch AS dbs_allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch, dbs.extra AS dbs_extra, dbs.encrypted_extra AS dbs_encrypted_extra, dbs.impersonate_user AS dbs_impersonate_user, dbs.server_cert AS dbs_server_cert, dbs.is_managed_externally AS dbs_is_managed_externally, dbs.external_url AS dbs_external_url, dbs.created_by_fk AS dbs_created_by_fk, dbs.changed_by_fk AS dbs_changed_by_fk 
FROM dbs 
WHERE dbs.id = ?]
[parameters: (1,)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
(venv) (base) mohnish@MMMDVMOHNISHSINT superset % FLASK_ENV=development superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

#### Environment

- browser type and version: chrome latest macos
- superset version: cloning directly from master branch of apache superset gihub repo
- python version:  3.9
- node.js version: 16.13.2

Answer (score 2):

Just delete `~.superset/superset.db` and run again it works fine!

Comment: This worked for me.  FWIW, I went all the way back to the step of installing external dependencies (`pip install -r requirements/testing.txt`), but monitoring the contents of `~/.superset/` I _think_ I could have skipped straight to initializing the database (`superset db upgrade`), which is the step in which `~.superset/superset.db` is created.